# How Can I Create a Primary key as Foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following fields

```
Student
-------------
std_id  PK
std_name
std_age


Library
----------
book_id  PK
book_name
book_isbn

OutGoing
----------------
studet_id
book_id
book_name
time
```

i want to use both std_id and book_id on OutGoing Table as foreign keys how can i do that?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: This site is loaded with examples. Search a bit. We don't need 1m repeat question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39394451

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 0):

You can make both `studet_id` and `book_id`  as `FOREIGN KEY`, But not as the primary key of your `OutGoing` table.So you need to create a new column `OutGoing_id` as the `PRIMARY KEY` of `OutGoing`  table. `PRIMARY KEY` should always be unique and should be the identity of the table to reference a column in the table.

```
    Student
    -------------
    std_id  PK
    std_name
    std_age


    Library
    ----------
    book_id  PK
    book_name
    book_isbn

    OutGoing
    ----------------
    OutGoing_id  -- PK for the table
    studet_id    -- FK 
    book_id      -- FK
    book_name
    time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like below

```
 OutGoing
 ----------------
    id  ( PK )
    studet_id (FK )
    book_id    ( FK)
    book_name
    time
```

Script :

```
ALTER TABLE OutGoing
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_OutGoing_Student_student_id
FOREIGN KEY (studet_id )
REFERENCES Student(std_id)


ALTER TABLE OutGoing
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_OutGoing_Library_book_id
FOREIGN KEY (book_id )
REFERENCES Library(book_id)
```